# Mean.js authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with mean.js for the first time and I see there is the Authentication provider already built in.

Their test Article page link is hidden if the user is not logged in but if I navigate manually to `/articles` I can see the page...

I think it is not very useful...

How can I restrict the access to all pages and redirect the user on the sign in page if not logged in?

What I tried so far is:

```
angular.module('core')
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location', 'Authentication', function ($rootScope, $state, $location, authentication) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    var notRestricted;
    if (toState.name === 'page.signin') {
      notRestricted = true;
    } else {
      notRestricted = false;
    }
    if (notRestricted) {
      return;
    }
    var user = authentication.user;
    if (!user) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('page.signin');
    }
  });
}]);
```

But if I navigate the the home page it start an infinite loop causing the `$digest` to crash the app.

Can someone help me to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest you extract the Authorization part of Daftmonk's angular full stack - its the best, here is mine [auth starter](https://github.com/jakblak/MEAN-Projects/tree/master/AuthStarter).

All you need to do is add a boolean in the routes to 'authenticate' like this:

```
  function config($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  });
```

This is what the code looks like in the app.js

```
function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  }

  function run($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
      // Add authorization token to headers
      request: function(config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        } else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is it possible to merge all this within meanjs without issues?

Comment: Its very hard because the projects use different structures.  angular full stack uses the 'features' design while mean.js uses a 'component' structure so all the controllers etc. are all in one folder - besides that there is a difference in syntax.